# Create a custom magento cron job

Tags: cron, email-templates, sql

Is it possible to create a custom magento cron job.
The task I want it can be done by

1. run sql query
2. using php to process some logic of the sql result
3. send out email to customer service.
4. cron job running like 10 minutes each

Above is possible solution can be done by the cron job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create custom cron in Magento [how to create custom cron](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cron-job/)  and set the time accordingly. or else you can create cli command visit here [how to create custom command](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html)
and set the cron on server

Comment: from my understanding that I can create a custom module, and then create a cron job to execute it right?

Comment: yes, or else you can create the required file in existing module

Comment: the link is helpful, I did create my own crontab and cron job.